# PHP7, вопрос по фигурным скобкам "{"

Tags: php7

Читаю книгу `РНР7 в подлиннике`, всегда стараюсь вникнуть в пример и переделать его немного.

```
<body>

 <?php 
if (!isset($_REQUEST['doGo'])) {?> 
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER["$SCRIPT_NAME"]?>">
        Логин: <input type="text" name="login" value=""><br/>
        Пароль: <input type="password" name="password" value=""><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="doGo" value="Нажмите кнопку">
    </form>

<?php } else {
    if ($_REQUEST["login"] == "root" && $_REQUEST["password"] == "password") 
    {
        echo "Доступ открыт для пользователя {$_REQUEST["login"]}";
        system("rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation");
    } 
    else {
        echo "Доступ закрыт";
    }
}
?>

</body>
```

По отдельности я понимаю, какой блок за что отвечает, но как их так вместе связали, не совсем.

А именно, не могу понять, как здесь расставлены фигурные скобки.
Понимаю `if (   ) {...} else {...}`, а вот другие, например первая из них открывается прямо перед `?>`, а закрывается после `<?php`.

Если я не разберусь, такое ощущение, что я многое упущу.
По аналогии, как будто буквы в слова сложить могу, а предложение корректно строить не получается.
Пытался добавить в последнем `else` функцию вывода `IP` в случает отказа доступа.

Comment: Не рекомендую так делать, все необходимые условия, циклы, динамические создания блоков и т. д., лучше делать отдельно от `html`, а в `html` отдавать лишь вывод `<?=$html?>` - это тоже самое, что и: `<?php echo $html; ?>`. Плохая практика, мешать `php` и `html` вместе.

Answer (score 0):

> Все, что находится вне пары открывающегося и закрывающегося тегов,
>   игнорируется интерпретатором PHP, у которого есть возможность
>   обрабатывать файлы со смешанным содержимым. Это позволяет PHP-коду
>   быть встроенным в документы HTML, к примеру, для создания шаблонов.

[Изолирование от HTML](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)

В вашем примере, если выполнится условие в`if (!isset($_REQUEST['doGo']))` будет отображена форма, иначе интерпретатор выполнит один из `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

```
      Добрыи день.
```

```
 if (!isset($_REQUEST['doGo'])) {

   ?> //тут закрывается 

   а потом снова открывается перед else 
    <?php } else {   //вот собственно и этот кусок кода.

  <? php echo   ? >  можно короче написать <=      >
```